# CSS - Problem with background when modal parent has relative position

Tags: css, angular, sass, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a modal that needs to be placed relative to a container. This is the layout in question that I want to create:

[image]

As you can see, this popup dropdown needs to act as a modal. The problem is that it needs to sit next to the filter. For this, I used absolute positioning on the dropdown.

However, since it is positioned relatively to the filters container, I am left with the dropdown completely unaccessible:

[image]

How can I get around this? Below you can find my code:

```
.backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 10;
}

.modal {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 62%;
    z-index: 20;
}

.content-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    top: $content-margin-top;
    z-index: 0;

    .filters-container {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

And my template looks something like this:

```
<div class="backdrop" [ngClass]="..."></div>
<div class="content-container">
    ...
    <div class="filters-container">
        ...
        <div class="modal"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You would need js for this to calculate the coordinates to place the modal due to z-index stacking context - as the backdrop is in the same context as the content container, it will always cover the modal - you would need to move the modal up to the same level as the backdrop (or inside the backdrop) and use js to position it where you want

Comment: If you don't want to use js, you could use a pseudo element to create the overlay: http://jsfiddle.net/jocnmzvh/1/ but this will only work if you don't have any positioned elements that are in the same stacking context that have a higher z-index (so I think your best option would be the js version)

Comment: Thanks a ton. I'm not a big fan of using pure JS hacks in my Angular projects so I will give the pseudo element suggestion a try!